# OrderBy Collection in Dictionary Value based on Property of the Collection

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

I'm having a `List<Department>`, in that it has **Department Name**, **List of Employees Name** and **OrderBy Dicrection** for List. Now I need to construct a `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Employee>>`, the **KEY** is a Department Name and the **Value** is an ObservableCollection by using `List<Department>`.

> **Expectation**: I need to **Sort** the `EmpName` within the `ObservableCollection<Employee>` which is present in `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Employee>> EmpList` based on `sortEmpName` Property which is in `List<Department> DepList` using
>   LINQ

I written the LINQ for this in the below Main() Function.

```
void Main()
{
    List<Department> DepList = new List<Department>()
    {
        new Department() { 
            DepName = "HR", 
            sortEmpName = FilterListSortDirection.SortDirection.Ascending, 
            EmpName = new List<string>() {"Raj", "Baba"}
        },
        new Department() {
            DepName = "iLab",
            sortEmpName = FilterListSortDirection.SortDirection.Descending,
            EmpName = new List<string>() {"Emma", "Kaliya"}
        },
        new Department() {
            DepName = "Testing",
            sortEmpName = FilterListSortDirection.SortDirection.None,
            EmpName = new List<string>() {"Supriya", "Billa"}
        }
    };


    Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Employee>> EmpList = DepList.Select(m => 
                                new {
                                    Dep = m.DepName,
                                    EmpCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(
                                                            m.EmpName.Select(k =>
                                                                new Employee() { EmpName = k, IsChecked = true }).ToList())
                                }
                            ).ToDictionary(x => x.Dep, x => x.EmpCollection);

}
```

The Model Classes are

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string DepName { get; set; }
    public FilterListSortDirection.SortDirection sortEmpName { get; set; }
    public List<string> EmpName { get; set; }
}

public class FilterListSortDirection
{
    public enum SortDirection
    {
        None,
        Ascending,
        Descending
    }
}
```

The Output Screen Shot of `List<Department> DepList`

[image]

The Output Screen Shot of `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Employee>> EmpList`

[image]

> **Expectation**: I need to **Sort** the `EmpName` within the `ObservableCollection<Employee>` which is present in `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Employee>> EmpList` based on `sortEmpName` Property which is in `List<Department> DepList` using
>   LINQ

This is a small part of a complex LINQ query in my project, so, I need to achieve this in LINQ. Kindly assist me.

- **HR** => List of Employee Names should be in **Ascending**
- **iLab** => List of Employee Names should be in **Descending**
- **Testing** => List of Employee Names should be in original order - **None** (i.e., No Change - Don't Sort)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like this:

```
var EmpList = DepList.ToDictionary(p => p.DepName, p =>
    {
        var empList = p.EmpName.Select(k => new Employee() { EmpName = k, IsChecked = true });
        if (p.sortEmpName == FilterListSortDirection.SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            empList = empList.OrderBy(q => q.EmpName);
        }
        else if (p.sortEmpName == FilterListSortDirection.SortDirection.Descending)
        {
            empList = empList.OrderByDescending(q => q.EmpName);
        }
        return new ObservableCollection<Employee>(empList.ToList());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use OrderBy

```
Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<Employee>> EmpList = DepList.Select(m => new
{
    Dep = m.DepName,
    EmpCollection = 
    m.sortEmpName == SortDirection.Ascending ? 
        new ObservableCollection<Employee>(m.EmpName.Select(k => new Employee {EmpName = k, IsChecked = true}).ToList().OrderBy(emp => emp.EmpName)) :
    m.sortEmpName == SortDirection.Descending ?
        new ObservableCollection<Employee>(m.EmpName.Select(k => new Employee { EmpName = k, IsChecked = true }).ToList().OrderByDescending(emp => emp.EmpName)) :
        new ObservableCollection<Employee>(m.EmpName.Select(k => new Employee { EmpName = k, IsChecked = true }).ToList())
}).ToDictionary(x => x.Dep, x => x.EmpCollection);
```